# Split Lines and Bold Text within a ui.alert Window in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I feel like this should be pretty simple, but I can't find anything about it. I want my message that pops up in a ui.alert window to bold certain words and split a string at `,` into new lines. Here is the code I have:

```
function send(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var bccSend = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2,2).getValue(); //value example is xxx@gmail.com, yyy@gmail.com
  var bccSendReplace = bccSend.toString().replace(/,/g,"<br>");
  var response = ui.alert('You are about to send this to the following email address(es): \n\n' + bccSendReplace + '\n\n Click OK to send, otherwise, close this box or click Cancel to abort.', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
}
```

The `bccSendReplace` is what I want to parse at commas into new lines. Instead, the code just replaces the comma with `<br>`. I would also like all text within `bccSendReplace` to be bold. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to use HTML tags for the method of `alert(prompt, buttons)` in Class Ui.
- You want to set `'You are about to send this to the following email address(es): \n\n' + bccSendReplace + '\n\n Click OK to send, otherwise, close this box or click Cancel to abort.'` to the bold type.

#### Modification point:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, the HTML cannot be used for the method of `alert(prompt, buttons)` in Class Ui. So as a workaround, how about using the custom dialog with the method of `showModalDialog` in Class Ui?

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script and run the function of `send`. By this, a dialog is opened. When the ok button and the cancel button are clicked, `clickOk()` and `clickCancel()` are run, respectively.

```
function send(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var bccSend = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var bccSendReplace = bccSend.toString().replace(/,/g,"<br>");
  
  const str = 'You are about to send this to the following email address(es): \n\n' + bccSendReplace + '\n\n Click OK to send, otherwise, close this box or click Cancel to abort.';
  const html = `
    <b>${str}</b><br>
    <input type="button" value="ok" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close()).clickOk()">
    <input type="button" value="cancel" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close()).clickCancel()">
  `;
  ui.showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'sample');
}

function clickOk() {
  // do something;
}

function clickCancel() {
  // do something;
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script is a simple script. So please modify it for your actual situation.
- Please run the script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [alert(prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,ButtonSet))
- [showModalDialog(userInterface, title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))

Comment: That's great. Thanks! Only issue I am having is when I click the buttons, nothing happens. For example, I have `function clickCancel() {throw new Error('Send Aborted.');} ` for the Cancel button. But nothing happens when clicked. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional information of `function clickCancel() {throw new Error('Send Aborted.');}`, when the cancel button is clicked, an error occurs at `clickCancel()`. By this, `withSuccessHandler` is not run. You can see the error at the console. For example, `function clickCancel() {SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Send Aborted.')}` is used, the alert dialog is opened.

Comment: hmmm...not quite understanding. Even if I replace what I have with exactly what you suggested, there is still nothing that happens when I click the close button for some reason.

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. I think that your current situation might be different from my understanding. But I would like to support you and resolve your additional issue. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information and your current script? Because your additional is different from your this question. By this, I would like to correctly confirm your new issue and think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.