# Setting Functions for Button Clicks within Modal Dialog in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a `send` function as follows [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112601/split-lines-and-bold-text-within-a-ui-alert-window-in-google-apps-script/):

```
function send(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var bccSend = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var bccSendReplace = bccSend.toString().replace(/,/g,"<br>");

  const str = 'You are about to send this to the following email address(es): \n\n' + bccSendReplace + '\n\n Click OK to send, otherwise, close this box or click Cancel to abort.';
  const html = `
    <b>${str}</b><br>
    <input type="button" value="ok" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close()).clickOk()">
    <input type="button" value="cancel" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close()).clickCancel()">
  `;
  ui.showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'sample');
}
```

I then have a function for when OK is clicked. If I just run this function, it runs as expected and there are no errors. However, When the OK button is clicked, it will not run this function.

```
 function clickOK() {
          var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
          copyDataFromForm();
          var sendDetails = getMeta(); Logger.log(sendDetails);
          //var officeSelection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2, 1).getValue();
          var subject = gen.setSubjectLine(sendDetails); Logger.log(subject);
          var BCC = '';
          var bccSend = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2,2).getValue();
          if(bccSend == ''){bccSend = sendDetails[6];}
          var toSend = main(sendDetails);//CreateHTML();
          var image = toSend[2]; 
          var attachment = [toSend[4].getAs(MimeType.PDF)];
          for(var i = 0; i<image.length; i++)
          {
            attachment.push(image[i]);
          }

          MailApp.sendEmail(sendDetails[7], subject, null, {
          name: 'Test ' + sendDetails[0].split(",", 1),
          htmlBody:toSend[3],
          inlineImages: toSend[1],
          attachments: attachment,
          cc:bccSend,
          replyTo:sendDetails[7]
          }); 
          ui.alert('Message has been sent.');
    }
```

And then here is the function for when Cancel is clicked. Again, if I run this function on its own, it runs just fine. But it is not called when the Cancel button is clicked.

```
function clickCancel() {SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Send Aborted.');}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

....UPDATE....
I have corrected the spelling error (it was correct in the script, just copied over an old portion of code by accident. This is the error I get within the browser once the `Cancel` button is clicked.

[image: The Error Message I get when I click the "Cancel" button.]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211402/discussion-on-question-by-hunter21188-setting-functions-for-button-clicks-within).

Answer (score 2):

**I believe it's just a spelling error**

`<input type="button" value="ok" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close()).clickOk()">` spelled clickOk

`function clickOK() {` spelled clickOK()

two caps on the end as opposed to one cap and lowercase

This is similar to your dialog and the buttons work.  Sorry I'm not comfortable with arrow notation yet.

```
function runTwo(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var bccSend = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet13').getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var bccSendReplace = bccSend.toString().replace(/,/g,"<br>");

  const str = 'You are about to send this to the following email address(es): \n\n' + bccSendReplace + '\n\n Click OK to send, otherwise, close this box or click Cancel to abort.';
  let html = `<b>${str}</b><br>`;
  html+='<input type="button" value="ok" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();}).clickOk()" />';
  html+='<input type="button" value="cancel" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();}).clickCancel()"/>';
  ui.showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'sample');
}

function clickCancel() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Clicked cancel');
}

function clickOk() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Click Ok')
}
```

Comment: Once I figured out how to pull up the browser error console, I was able to see that was an error from a previous version of code. That's been fixed. Thanks. But unfortunately neither button works still. See the updated question for a description of the error message I am getting. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Cooper. That does work just fine when I copy it in a brand new google sheet. No clue why it is spitting out the error I get when I try to run it within my current project (see error message in updated portion of the question). Wondering if it has something to do with a library I use...but I'm not calling that at all, so don't see why it would be that.